# Add a request header while redirecting in NGINX

Tags: http, nginx, routes

I have a simple redirect rule like

```
location = /redirect-me {
    return 307 http://localhost:3001/redirect-me;
}
```

There will be a POST call to the `redirect-me` url, all I want to do is to redirect the post call to another server.

But how can I add a X-Header to the `request header` going to http://localhost:3001/.

I tried both `add_header` and `proxy_set_header`.`add_header` is adding the header to the *response header* not the *request header*.

```
location = /redirect-me {
    add_header 'X-Header-a' 'cust_info';
    proxy_set_header 'X-Header-p' 'cust_info';
    return 307 http://localhost:3001/redirect-me;
}
```

and `proxy_set_header` is not adding anything.

So how can I add a header to the request while redirecting with 307. ?

Comment: When you use the `return` directive, you instruct a *client* to perform a redirect. The redirect is happening on the client side. There is no way you can enforce the client to send a header. It is up to the client to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `proxy_pass` directive instead of a redirect. I supplied the link below for the docs which includes an example of setting headers.

```
location /redirect-me {
    proxy_set_header 'X-Header-p' 'cust_info';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/redirect-me;
}
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: As I mentoned, there will be a POST call to the URL, and will that be passed by `proxy_pass`

Comment: I see nothing in your post about `proxy_pass` specifically. You state you want to redirect the post call to another server. I believe changing your `return 307` to a `proxy_pass` will solve your problem.